# cannot downloads file using python socket programming

Tags: python, sockets, wifi, ethernet, download-manager

i want to download a file from this url (http://justlearn.16mb.com/a.jpg) using python sockets only and i dont know how to do it as i am a novice in python.

Actually my main goal is to download files in half part using wifi connection and other half part using ethernet connection.

Thank you in advance for helping.

```
import os
import socket

tcpd = 'http://justlearn.16mb.com/a.jpg'
portd = 80
ipd = socket.gethostbyname('http://justlearn.16mb.com/a.jpg')
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((tcpd,portd))



BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

with open('a.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    print ('file opened')
    while True:
        #print('receiving data...')
        data = s.recv(1024)
        #print('data=%s', (data))
        if not data:
            f.close()
            break
        # write data to a file
        f.write(data)

print('Successfully get the file')
s.close()
print('connection closed')
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like this instead. I am unable to test it due to a proxy, but the example should help you in the right direction. Using sockets directly would make this unnecessarily difficult.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import http.client


def main():
    connection = http.client.HTTPConnection('justlearn.16mb.com')
    connection.request('GET', '/a.jpg')
    response = connection.getresponse()
    if response.status != 200:
        raise RuntimeError(response.reason)
    with open('a.jpg', 'wb') as file:
        while not response.closed:
            buffer = response.read(1 << 12)
            if not buffer:
                break
            file.write(buffer)
    connection.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is another example that is shorter and uses the `urlopen` function from the `urllib.request` package instead. The code is simpler since the HTTP code is handled in the background instead.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
from urllib.request import urlopen


def main():
    with urlopen('http://justlearn.16mb.com/a.jpg') as source, \
            open('a.jpg', 'wb') as destination:
        while True:
            buffer = source.read(1 << 12)
            if not buffer:
                break
            destination.write(buffer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks , but then by using this urllib or http.client lib , i think i won't be able to force my program to use a specific network adapter like i have two internet connection one wifi and ethernet. i want to able to download using ethernet while i want to surf in browser using wifi

Comment: @SAGARAGRAWAL How are you forcing a specific network adapter to be used in your code?

Comment: i am thinking of using windows native netsh command to add specific route to specific destination ip from particular network interface or this s.bind(('192.168.0.1', 0))
s.connect(('...'))

Answer (score 0):

How big is the file? I'm assuming it's bigger than 1KB. When you write `s.recv(1024)`, you are only receiving 1024 bytes. Try a bigger number as the parameter.

It really would be easier to use urllib.request, at least try and if you can't "force my program to use a specific network adapter", then never mind.